# Finding data from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My table is :

| loginid | name | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | abc | analyst |
| 12 | abc | clerk |
| 142 | xyz | clerk |
| 142 | xyz | manager |
| 1 | yash | manager |
| 1 | yash | ceo |
| 2 | aarav | president |
| 2 | aarav | ceo |

I want to display each login id once and if it has two or more than two roles it is expected to show this result :

| loginid | name | role | role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | abc | clerk | analyst |
| 142 | xyz | manager | clerk |
| 1 | yash | ceo | manager |
| 2 | aarav | ceo | president |

but then I was able to write following query :

```
select a.loginid,a.name,a.role,b.role 
from tb1 a,tb1 b 
where a.loginid=b.loginid and a.role<>b.role;
```

what can I do to resolve the issue? as the result i am getting is :

| loginid | name | role | role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | abc | clerk | analyst |
| 12 | abc | analyst | clerk |
| 142 | xyz | manager | clerk |
| 142 | xyz | clerk | manager |
| 1 | yash | ceo | manager |
| 1 | yash | manager | ceo |
| 2 | aarav | ceo | president |
| 2 | aarav | president | ceo |

Comment: This is PIVOT. Not supported by MySQL. Emulate.

Comment: which database do you use? mysql or another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you aggregate the roles into a single column:

```
select loginid, name, group_concat(role order by role) as roles
from t
group by loginid, name;
```

If you want exactly two columns for the roles (as in the question you asked), you can also use `min()` and `max()`:

```
select loginid, name, min(role), nullif(max(role), min(role))
from t
group by loginid, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Gordon Linoff's answer, using group_concat() in subquery, we can futher split string into **columns** to imitate table pivot.

In case of `n` roles maximum for each person, we can handle it with a MySQL Stored Procedure, defined and used like this:

```
#
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_GetRoles;
#
DELIMITER $$
#
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetRoles()
BEGIN 
    
    DECLARE i, n INT;
    
    SELECT COUNT(role) c INTO n FROM tb1 GROUP BY loginid ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1;
    
    # get SQL string:
    #
    # role 1:
    SET @s = 'SELECT loginid, name,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(roles, '','', 1), '','', -1) AS role';

    # from role 2:
    SET i = 2;

  WHILE i <= n DO
    SET @s = CONCAT(@s, ',
    IF(LENGTH(roles) - LENGTH(REPLACE(roles, '','', '''')) + 1 > ', i - 1, ',
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(roles, '','', ', i, '), '','', -1),
      ''''
    ) AS role');
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;

  #
  # add other clauses:
    SET @s = CONCAT(@s, '
  FROM (SELECT
    loginid, name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(role) AS roles
  FROM 
    tb1
  GROUP BY 
    loginid, name) t
  ');
  
  #
  # execute the dynamic statement:
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s; 
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END$$

DELIMITER ;

#CALL sp_GetRoles();
```

This will fit to cases where some loginid has more then 2 roles.

The maximum roles `n` for each person is obtained by:

```
SELECT COUNT(role) c INTO n FROM tb1 GROUP BY loginid ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1;
```

To illustrate this, we add 2 roles for aarev:

```
INSERT INTO tb1 VALUES(2, 'aarav', 'analyst');
INSERT INTO tb1 VALUES(2, 'aarav', 'engineer');
```

`CALL sp_GetRoles();` will give this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much..though I wanted to work it for n (not defined) number of roles. the solution you gave is working for max three:)

Comment: @Pooja_1, i've added n roles case. I hope this helps and you appreciate it.